# getElementById is returning undefined from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to retrieve the value of an `<p>` element "sectionS" and then display it in another `<p>` element "sS" by using `getElementById`. The output I get is 'undefined' when it should be 2. If I use the `<input>` element instead of the

element it works.

I've spent about 6 hours looking for an answer. I haven't found anything on this site that relates to this.

```
<body>

<table id="solidTable">

  <tr>    
    <td><p id="sectionS"></p></td>
    <td><p id="sS"></p></td>    
  </tr>

</table>
```

Script:

```
<script>

   document.getElementById("sectionS").innerHTML = 2;
   y = document.getElementById("sectionS").value;
   document.getElementById("sS").innerHTML = y;

</script>
```

Comment: Because `sectionS` is a `<p>`, so it dosesn't have a `.value`

Comment: Only input elements have a `.value`. I'm a bit surprised that you *assign to* `innerHTML` but *read from* `value`. Doesn't this seem odd to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

paragraph tags don't have `value` property. Use `innerHTML` to get the correct value.

Change

```
y = document.getElementById("sectionS").value;
```

To

```
y = document.getElementById("sectionS").innerHTML;
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n7gtq9q6/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sqcmhr4q/ demonstrates this. use .value and you get "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to fetch innerHTML of the sectionS rather than value.

```
<script>

  document.getElementById("sectionS").innerHTML = 2;
  var y = document.getElementById("sectionS").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("sS").innerHTML = y;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `.value` to retrieve the content of the paragraph tag... better to use `.innerHTML`, `.innerText` or `.textContent`

`.value` points attribute value of the element.

```
<option value="123">text goes here</option>
//      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

`.innerText`, `.innerHTML` and `.textContent` points content of the element.

```
<option value="123">text goes here</option>
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: *".value points attribute value of the element."* That's not 100% correct. There is a big difference between the value **property** and the value **attribute**: The *property* holds the *current* value, whereas the *attribute* holds the initial value. Of course there is no observable difference for `<option>` elements since their value does not change, but you will see the difference with `<input>` elements.